# Удаление данных из таблицы PHP

Tags: php, html

Следующим кодом формируется таблица в html и выводятся данные из массива:

```
for ($j=1; $j<($n+2); $j++){
    $res=$res.'<tr>';
    for ($i=1; $i<4; $i++){
        if (($i==3) and ($j>=2)) {
            $res=$res.'<td><INPUT type="submit" value="Удалить"></td>';
        } else {
            $res=$res.'<td>'.$arr[$j][$i].'</td>';
        }
    }
    $res=$res.'</tr>';
}
$res=$res.'</table>';
echo $res;
```

Массив $arr хранит данные, полученные из таблицы MySQL. В последней ячейке каждой строки в таблице создается кнопка "Удалить". Как можно сделать следующее:

1. Сохранить значение ячейки первого столбца массива со второй строки (для каждой строки).
2. Передать это значение другому скрипту по нажатию кнопки "Удалить" для удаления этой строки в таблице БД?

Comment: Передавайте айди в массив.А потом по айди удаляйте запись

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. тега "javascript" не стоит в задаче, полагаю, что её нужно решить без его участия. Тогда Ваш кусочек:

```
$res = $res.'<td><INPUT type="submit" value="Удалить"></td>';
```

Замените на:

```
$res = $res . '<td>
            <form action="адрес_скрипта_куда_передаете_удаление" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="act" value="delete">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$arr[$j][1].'">
                <input type="submit" value="Удалить">
            </form>
        </td>';
```

Comment: Вариант со ссылкой лучше убрать.

Comment: @ArchDemon, да, Вы правы, тогда ещё не знал, что это является нехорошей практикой